# Why does this SVG work being viewed raw in the browser but not in a webpage?

Tags: html, http, svg, http-headers, content-type

[This SVG](http://54.186.131.77/Style/Resources/SVG/logo.svg) can be viewed correctly in my browser window.

However when I try to use it as an image in a web page (tried this on my live site and in JSFiddle), it does not show up:

```html
<img src="http://54.186.131.77/Style/Resources/SVG/logo.svg"/>
```

Each time, my server claims that the file was successfully served, yet it doesn't render.

**What is the issue?**

---

In case you think my issue could involve my serving method / MIME types, [I've created a Gist with my Node.js custom server implementation.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a39603f3ee74694e8186) I treat `.svg` as `text/xml` according to whatever chart I used when developing this server some time ago.

Comment: Have you tried setting MIME types, and what is running on the server side? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338648/svg-wont-display
Apache instructions - http://planetsvg.com/tools/mime.php#apache

Comment: @Mousey I'll show you how my server handle's MIME types.

Comment: @Mousey it's too much code to clutter this question with, since I dont know which part could be problematic in order to `...[snip]...`, so here it is in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a39603f3ee74694e8186

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918977/right-mime-type-for-svg-images-fonts

Comment: @TylerH this is an unusual question in the fact that examples given as not working now work properly once the answer was found. I was serving an applicable but imperfect MIME type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Content-type` response header when I load that svg from your server is currently `Content-Type:text/xml`, which is an incorrect MIME type for SVG. Try changing your `Content-type` header to `image/svg+xml`.

From the gist you posted in your comment, it looks like you will be able to do this by changing line 15 from:

```
'.svg'  : 'text/xml',
```

to

```
'.svg'  : 'image/svg+xml',
```

I would recommend against just changing the markup, because that is just a short-term fix for the incorrect HTTP headers.

Comment: I actually changed the content type as you said and reloaded the server, reloaded the page with cache disabled - problem wasn't solved -, but to be sure, is it possible to check the content type being served via javascript so I can know for sure the MIME type is served correctly?

Comment: @JonathanTodd I checked again and it looks like your content type is now `text/svg-xml` - still incorrect. To check the content type, go to [web-sniffer.net](http://web-sniffer.net/) and plug in your SVG url, leaving everything else default. Then check the "HTTP Response Header" section for a `Content-Type` of `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: Ahh I see. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it, using plain old HTML. I used the answer shown in the SO link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files) to figure it out.

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head>
>   <meta charset="utf-8" />
>   <title>Test page</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>   <object data="http://54.186.131.77/Style/Resources/SVG/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
>       <img src="http://54.186.131.77/Style/Resources/SVG/logo.svg" />
>   </object>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```