# How to create .htaccess to display SVG's?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, svg, cpanel

I'm testing a website that has worked great locally however when I upload it to my godaddy server my SVG's are not rendering in browser.

After some web searches and working with tech support I learned I need to have a .htaccess file configured in my image folder directory to correctly display SVG's.

Can someone please let me know how to create, download, or copy and paste the correct data for a .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean setting a proper `Content-Type` header. The [MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918977/right-mime-type-for-svg-images-with-fonts-embedded) is apparently `image/svg+xml` and you can use the [AddType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) directive:

```
# Add one line for each extension
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Is that all that's needed "AddType image/svg+xml .svg"?  I put that in the same directory as SVG's and re-uploaded but nothing seemed to change.  I named the file "svg.htacess". Does the name matter?

Comment: @ab3d_work You're actually looking for a file called `.htaccess`, as in "dot-htaccess". https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-htaccess-2504

Comment: I think I'm making progress! changing the name to ".htaccess" no troughs a ""500 internal error". So now I have a .htaccess in the image folder with my svg's. This is whats in my .htaccess:

Comment: AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

Comment: is there anything else that should be in there other than those 2 lines?

Comment: Error 500 means that Apache is parsing your `.htaccess` file but there's something wrong with it. You should have a look at the logs—GoDaddy will possibly have a tool in their control panel.